# Closed Loop Gain Approximation

Tags: transfer-function, feedback

In Razavi's [*Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits*](http://d1.amobbs.com/bbs_upload782111/files_44/ourdev_669891QWSQZ8.pdf), how does he manipulate equation 8.5 into 8.6 below?

[image: Razavi Chapter 8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's high school math. Take \$\frac{1}{AB}=x\$. Then multiply the num. and denom. of the relation for \$\frac{Y}{X}\$ by x: You get \$\frac{Y}{X}=\frac{1}{B}.(1+x)^{-1}\$. Using [binomial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_approximation) and noting that x is much less than the unity, the approximation becomes \$ \frac{Y}{X} \approx\ \frac{1}{B}[1-x]\$ or \$ \frac{Y}{X}\ \approx\ \frac{1}{B}[1-\frac{1}{AB}]\$. Note that this approximation neglects second and higher order terms in the Taylor series of the function \$\frac{Y}{X}\$. \end

Comment: *I think it's high school math* My thoughts exactly but I was too lazy to prove it. Indeed terms are neglected and also in these approximations certain assumptions are made, for example that \$A\$ is large. Then we end up with \$\frac1 \beta\$ which is easy, insightful and also "close enough" for practical situations.

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to get the approximation given in (8.6).

[image]

However, for me I don't like that approach much. Usually assign T as a loop gain and then make approximation depending on magnitude of T compared to 1.

[image]